# Iterating over JavaScript array returnws from python list

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, plotly

I am trying to traverse a Python list by converting it into a JavaScript array and then use it in the plotly.plot function.

For now I have used jinja syntax to convert my python list to a JS array but when i tried to get a value by indexing, it does not give me a result.

```
var allgraphs ={{allchart|safe}};


    names=[]

   for (i = 0; i <allgraphs.length-1; i++)

    {
    var mynum = {{numbers|safe}}


    name = 'chart';
    value=name.concat(i);
    names.push(value);
    Plotly.plot(names[i],allgraphs[i],{}); 
    }   

</script>
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is the difference in python list and js array?

Comment: wouldn't it be good to use an intermediate standardized format like JSON ?

Comment: how can i convert it into an standardized format ?

Comment: json.dumps(dt[j],cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder) I have used this code in my flask file

Comment: import json;
my_list = [ ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’];
my_json_string = json.dumps(my_list)

Comment: if some how i can change this variable value through loop , i think my problem will be solved var graphs3 ={{allchart[0]|safe}}; instead of hardcoded value like 0 it should be incremental

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediate standardized format like JSON.

encode it in your python using

```py
import json
jsonString = json.dumps(yourArray)
```

and the on the javascript part you do

```js
let jsonString = // the value of jsonString at the end of preceding python snippets
let yourArray = JSON.parse(variable)
```

then use `yourArray` like you would do with any other js array since it's one of them

Comment: `var allgraphs ={{allchart|safe}};  let yourArray =JSON.parse(allgraphs)`   like this?

Comment: @adnan tbh I don't know where the `{{allchart|safe}}` come from nor what it means, but JSON already take case of all the safety you need against special charater so maybe ` let yourArray =JSON.parse(allchart)` is enough

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & `
I am getting this error

Comment: if some how i can change this variable value through loop , i think my problem will be solved
`var graphs3 ={{allchart[0]|safe}};`
instead of hardcoded value like 0 it should be incremental